# Linux open a new port for my application on HTTPS

Tags: java, linux

I have deployed a new HTTPS application in a linux box. HTTPS port configured is 9443.

Then with the below command, I opened the port 9443:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9443/tcp --permanent
```

Then after starting the application, when I run netstat, I got the below message:

```
[root@xxxx init.d]# netstat -lpn | grep 9443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12789/java
```

Does this mean the port is opened?

I am unable to access my application from browser. Its complaining that "This site can’t be reached".

Any idea?

Comment: seems like the port is open and in listening state. try telnet to yourself and see if its working ">telnet localhost 9443"

Comment: u may also try ">curl --insecure https://localhost:9443" just to make sure its not an ssl certificate issue

Comment: [root@xxxx init.d]# curl --insecure servername:9443
curl: (7) Failed connect to admdmapp02v:9443; Connection refused

Comment: telnet servername 9443
Trying ipaddress...
telnet: connect to address ipaddress: No route to host

Comment: Also in localhost_access_log, I am not seeing any requests coming in. Any  idea?

Comment: if telnet 9443 cannot connect it means that the underlying TCP is not working (HTTPS using TCP as well as TELNET), also the "No route to host" message indicate that it maybe a firewall problem. try disabling the firewall or any security tool that may block and try again

Comment: What do you mean by HTTPS using TCP as well as TELNET? I opened 9443 as a TCP port. Is this not enough for HTTPS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121382/discussion-between-chenchuk-and-ani).